# Back press in my activity go back to my first activity

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I make a flutter application with a lot of activities, but when i press the back press buttom in any activity, it will back to the first activity in main.dart.
Why is that? And how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using `Navigator.push()` to navigate between screen, having them stacked and not replaced

```
Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
  );
```

see [Navigate to a new screen and back](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics)

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the behaviour of `Navigator()`

Please take a look at the documentation: [Navigator class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html)

But to give you more information about your specific problem I will try to help with this concepts. **Pop** and **Push**

Tha navigator have a stack (like a pile, like the image below).

- If you "push" --> you add one page (to the top of the pile).
- If you "pop" --> you remove one page (from the top of the pile).
- When you **press BACK** --> you remove one page (like pop).

[image]

When moving from one page to another, you must "push" the new route to the navigator stack.

So I guess, you are doing something like `popAndPushNamed` in your code... so you are first popping the last page and then pushing the new page.

You need to change your code to only **push** (without pop).
That way, your stack will preserve the "history" of your previous navigation.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are looking for something like `willpopscope`
you can handle the back button, or do nothing.. or do a push do another page

example willpopscope

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Test'),
      ),
      body: new WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          print("here you can handle the back button, with return false nothing happens, you can push to some other pages..");
          return false;
        },
        child: new Container()
      ),
    );
```